# How to align dropdown navigation of ActionBar to right in HoneyComb Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I am new to Android development.

I have spinnerAdapter and I passed it to Dropdown navigator of Actionbar.
But It shows Dropdown list on left side of ActionBar.

I want to show that List on Right side of ActionBar.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could align action bar item on left or right by only adding custom view on action bar and add buttons etc in that customview (may be a relative layout )and you can align item inside this customview

Thank

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible, or if it is I don't believe there's a solution which involves the built in navigator.

This was something that was investigated a while back for the project that I'm working on and we came to the conclusion that on the left is where it is meant to reside.